# Hibernate (or EntityManager?) adding "where 0=1" to query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I'm using the JPA EntityManager + Hiberate, and a myserious piece of the where clause is appearing. The debug from Hibernate is basically showing:

```
select /* bunch of columns */
from some_table
where /* several filters */
  and 0=1
```

This is happening when running `javax.persistence.Query.getResultList`. The `Query` has an array of `Predicates` in its where clause, but rest assured that `0 = 1` is not one of them.

I can find no possible reason why the `0=1` part is included in the query. Any ideas? I'd search for an answer first, but search engines ignore `=`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how a disjunction is translated to SQL. See the [javadoc for disjunction()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#disjunction%28%29)

> Create a disjunction (with zero disjuncts). A disjunction with zero disjuncts is false.

So, when an empty disjunction is created, it only contains the clause `1 = 0` (false). When additional predicates are added to the disjunction, they're simply added to the initial (false) one, separated with an `or`:

```
where 1 = 0 or ...
```

If you use a conjunction, it will be translated to

```
where 1 = 1 and ...
```

Comment: Bingo. I just debugged through my code that's creating the Predicates and found that it build a disjunction with nothing in it. Problem solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @JB Nizet answer, but to make it more concrete. In my case, I am using a CriteriaBuilder and the issue is that I am creating a list of predicates programmatically. In some cases, it generates an empty list of predicates and when I apply:

```
criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {})));
```

Appears the `0=1` issue. Simply checking if the predicates list is empty or not, and avoiding to adding to the where clause in the case it is empty, solves the issue.